# vectorized block assign with overlopping values

Tags: matlab, vectorization

So I ran into this bug today

```
A_TEST(dest,:)=A_TEST(source,:)+A_TEST(dest,:);
A_TEST(:,dest)=A_TEST(:,source)+A_TEST(:,dest);
```

If dest is non-unique, this fails (which makes sense). So my quick fix is to do a for loop over dest

```
for (k=1:numel(dest))
    A(dest(k),:)=A(source(k),:)+A(dest(k),:);
    A(:,dest(k))=A(:,source(k))+A(:,dest(k));
end
```

And matlab is bad at such for loops. How would one vectorize this call?

Comment: Sorry, just to make sure; do you _want_ the multiplicity?

Comment: I want the multiplicity. Source is unique, but dest is not.

Comment: Matlab is not bad at loops, with JIT compilation, especially with simple loops, they are often as efficient as vectorised code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With the following, I show how to do it with rows. 
To do it with columns, it's a similar approach but different code, I'll explain why.

To summarize, you have a matrix A, with n rows and p columns.
You have a list of integers in the range `[1,n]`, `src`, and idem for `dst`.
I'm assuming that they both have the same size, and might contain more than n elements (so that there are repetitions in both potentially).

Grouping the `src`s by `dst`s, it's clear that the operation you're talking about is equivalent to a linear recombination of rows. This is equivalent to a pre-multiplication by a `n x n` matrix in which element `(i,j) = k` means "the recombination corresponding to the destination row i contains row j with multiplicity k".

This is what the following code does:

```
function A = madScience( A, src, dst )

    n = size(A,1);
    M = eye(n);

    ix = sub2ind( [n,n], dst, src );

    [ux,~,mlt] = unique( ix );
    nux = length(ux);
    mlt = accumarray( mlt(:), 1, [nux,1] );

    M(ux) = M(ux) + mlt';
    A     = M*A;

end
```

**Note 1:** The two codes that you give in your post are **NOT** equivalent; you would need two separate `for` loops to make them equivalent.

**Note 2:** The same operation on columns is equivalent to a post multiplication by a matrix in which element `(i,j) = k` means "the recombination corresponding to column j contains column i with multiplicity k".

**Note 3:** If A is square, then both operations can be performed with the same matrix M as `(M*A) * M'` (the parenthesis are important).

Comment: Pretty smart approach! +1

Comment: Nice...I figured it would be some sort of accumarray madness.

Comment: Point that I didn't mention in the original post was that the matrix is actually diagonally semetrical (weighted adjacency matrix). We can do this all with just the row combinations...nice!